# Excel Formula to List all not matching values between two named ranges based on criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, match, named-ranges

i need your help to achive a list of all **none-matching** values between two different ranges (actually, in different sheets too, but since i'm using named ranges, shoudn't be a problem).

This is the first range and it's values:

[image]

It contains the names of certain individuals who had been evaluated at work. Note that the values start on cell `A3`, since `A1` and `A2` contains header values.

Next range:

[image]

On `Column A` you'll find a list of all Executives that are or have been on the company. On `Column B` are the exit dates of theese people. If they're still working, it'll say "On Duty".

**What i want is a Formula to list all people from the "Executives Name List" that are "On Duty" but not among the "Evaluated Name" list.**

This are the named ranges that i use and the expected output:

[image]

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Array Formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(executives,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF($I$2:I2,executives)=0)*(exit_date="On Duty")*(ISERROR(MATCH(executives,evaluated_name,0))),0)),"")
```

The output list must be in the third row.  Change the `I` to refer to the column into which you want the output.  If a different starting row is wanted then change the `2` to the row above the first formula, even if it is the title row.

Being an Array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have used the names for the ranges in the opposite way, `evaluated_name` refers to `D3:D11` and `executives` refers to `A3:A7`. Please update your answer as it will get very confusing for future users...

Comment: @EEM I assumed they were in order.

Comment: @EEM it is fixed and thanks for the catch and sorry for the quick angry response.  It was undeserved.  I will use the 'It's been a long day' excuse.

Comment: actually it was right before the edition. that's why i showed data ordered and put titles related to the named ranges.